# Is there a way to state multiple conditions associated with another condition as a whole?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, bitwise-operators

I am trying to consolidate a few different if statements.  What I am trying to accomplish  would read something like this:

If (this is true and this is true) OR (this is true and this is true) AND (This is true)

So, one at least one of the first two sets of parentheses would need to be true, and if one of those is true, then also the last set of parentheses would need to be true, in order for the code inside to be executed.

Here is the specific code I am (unsuccessfully) trying to make work:

```
 if(($calc->number % 2 == 1 && $calc->doubleColor == 'b2' | $calc->number % 2 == 0 && $calc->doubleColor = 'r2') && in_array($calc->number, $backToBet)){

  }
```

Is there a way to do this? A possibility? Is there any drawback to getting a lot into a single if statement?

**EDIT**

```
  $blackMatch = $calc->number % 2 == 1 && $calc->doubleColor == 'b2';
  $redMatch = $calc->number % 2 == 0 && $calc->doubleColor = 'r2';
  $numberMatch = in_array($calc->number, $backToBet);

 if(($blackMatch || $redMatch) && $numberMatch){
   }

/ ** Calc->number = 2,  $blackMatch = false, $redMatch = false, 
     $numberMatch array contains 2 **/
```

Basically what I end with is a 'true' result, even though neither of the conditions within the inner parentheses are satisfied.

Comment: You need to use `||` for OR, not `|` which is the bitwise OR operator. Otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: Try adding the parentheses in Ilya's answer that are missing from yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make code easier to read, I'd suggest to use separate variables, like this:

```
$condition1 = ($calc->number % 2 == 1) && ($calc->doubleColor == 'b2');
$condition2 = ($calc->number % 2 == 0) && ($calc->doubleColor == 'r2');
$condition3 = in_array($calc->number, $backToBet);
if (($condition1 || $condition2) && $condition3) {
}
```

two things to note:

1. `||` is logical OR, `|` is bitwise OR
2. `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment

Comment: And using the correct kind of OR (which you did but didn't point out).

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah, added note about it

Comment: I set it up exactly as in your example, but it still returns true only based on what appears to be the 3rd condition.  Because neither of the first two conditions would return true in my case.  I am baffled.

Comment: @GabrielLuciano print all variables to debug the problem

Comment: I don't know if you meant to print them on my own end or to print them here so you could have a look.  I printed them back in my answer just in case. (They are the results of my var_dump which I have been using to debug.)

Comment: @GabrielLuciano you haven't replaced `=` with `==`

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Not only was I able to fix the problem but I understand a little more now.  Thanks!!!